# Convert C# Windows forms code to C# Android code

Tags: c#, android, windows-forms-designer, code-conversion

I recently made a program in Windows Forms using Visual Studio but my friends asked me to make an app for it. I then noticed that Visual Studio has made it possible to make apps directly in C#. But when I opened a new project it was different from what I'm used to (obviously).

What I'm looking for is an easy way to convert my old windows forms code into the Android format but since I'm generally new to programming I don't know how myself. Do any of you have any tips or good tutorials that can help me? I have been googling around but didn't find anything that helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't automatically. With Xamarin you can write your app in c# but you must rewrite a lot code, specially ui interface. Maybe you can reuse some functions and logic

Comment: What I wanted was to know if there's an easy way to rewrite the same code but in the structure of Android without rewriting it completely but I guess there isn't such a way

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't think it is possible.

Windows forms is Windows Forms and Android is Android, these are two separate things that could be joined using Mono (Xamarin) for example.

The code will not transform on it's own, and magically follow Android logic. To create Android apps, you must learn Android.